# Confused with the notation about category of abelian groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, abelian-groups

The following text is from an [MIT open course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-905-algebraic-topology-i-fall-2016/lecture-notes/MIT18_905F16_lec4.pdf).

> Let the category $\mathcal{C}=\text{Ab}$. Let $f:A \to B$ be a split
>    epi and $g:B \to A$ be a section of $f$. Let $\iota: \text{ker}A \to
>  A$ be the inclusion map. Then we have the map $$[g \quad \iota]: B
>  \oplus  \text{ker}A \to A$$

What does it mean by the map $[g \quad \iota]$? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to know how the map is defined? $(b, a) \in B \oplus \text{ker}A \mapsto g(b) + a$.

Answer (score 2):

These notes were produced by students taking notes during lectures. (They seem not too useful without the context of the lecture.)

At any rate, this is most likely the [copairing](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copairing) which in the case of an [additive category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/additive+category) is simply the sum of the morphisms  $g\circ\pi_1$ and $\iota\circ\pi_2$ where the $\pi_i$ are projections. The copairing is often written $[g,\iota]$ and that might be what led to what was in the notes. As the nLab article states, often this is written vertically $\begin{bmatrix}g\\\iota\end{bmatrix}$.

That said, they are using a more matrix-like notation. We can [express maps between finite biproducts generally in a matrix form](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/matrix+calculus). In this context, $\begin{pmatrix}h\\k\end{pmatrix}:A\to B\oplus C$ would mean the pairing map for $h:A\to B$ and $k:A\to C$, i.e. $a\mapsto (h(a),k(a))$, and $\begin{pmatrix}g&\iota\end{pmatrix}:B\oplus\ker A\to A$ would be the copairing.

Comment: It seems to me that in the matrix notation, a copairing should be written as a row and a pairing as a column, so the notation here makes perfect sense.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I switched the meaning of the $m$ and $n$ around from the nLab page. I've made some edits.

Answer (score 1):

I guess they mean $[g \;\;\; \iota] = g + \iota$ defined pointwise, i.e a tuple $(b,a)$ is send to $g(b) + a$.